# Categorizing Instagram geo-tags

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I'm looking to add a feature on my application that lists bars and restaurants around a device and orders them by the amount of recent posts that have gone up under their geo-tag.

Think Instagram's "Trending Places" screen but only bars and restaurants.

Is there a way to categorize or limit Instagram's list of geo-tags to bars and restaurants?

I know that Instagram pulls their geo-tags from Facebook Places and that they are categorized within that. Is there a way to link these up?

I'm kind of new at this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google Places API, have the feature that you want. https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: Will Google Places be able to match up with the Instagram geo-tags?

Comment: it has to be Instagram's "Trending Places" or just be like ? ( you can search the places around you, and see info about it in google API)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the Facebook Place API to get the locations around your device.

After that, use the /locations/search from Instagram (which accepts the FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID) to get the Instagram location-id. And once you have the location-id, use the /locations/location-id/media/recent to get the recent media.